# C# simple regex for replacing "\ / : * ? " < > |"

Tags: c#, regex

hey there!
im not really into regular expressions, but i need a simple regex for replacing all of the following chars:

\ / :  * ? " < > |

thanks^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you have it:

```
[\\/:*?"<>|]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be the following? 
[\\/:\*\?'<>|]

Comment: @jeremiah You usually use @"" strings for regex, so only the " needs escaping.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: OK -- I thought it was C++, which needed more things escaped.

Comment: @Mark: It's inside a character class so you shouldn't need to escape things that are metacharacters only *outside* of character classes.

Comment: @abc: I gave you the regex. How you need to represent it in your language is up to you. If you stick it into a normal C# string then you need to use `"[\\\\/:*?\"<>|]"` anyway.

Answer (score -3):

here is an eg which can be helpful to u

CAP*!(ITAL)!('CINE)!(CAP [A-Z])

finds CAP but not when followed by ITAL or 'CINE or when followed by a space and a world beginning with a capital letter.

Comment: How is that helpful for the question?